# Internet only works for youtube

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I have this weird problem on my Ubuntu 14.04, where I could only access youtube. The problem starts after keeping I suspend my laptop multiple times(probably 5-6 times) and then in the middle of this session internet stops working. The thing which is weird is:

1. Youtube works and none other website loads.
2. All my devices are connected to same wifi router where all the websites are accessible.

I am an amateur in network connection problems. I tried googling the problem but did not get a proper response. One of the things I tried was  disabling WMM.

Comment: Does your ISP give IPV6? It is a known problem that after suspend you do not get an IPV4 address. Does google work? ;-)

Comment: Yes, Google doea work

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Ubuntu. When you have IPV6 addressing, sometimes after suspend you do not get an IPV4 address.

You can check it by looking into Network manager -> Connections. You will see only IPV6 address.

A workaround is to disconnect from your wireless router and connect again.

I tried to report the bug to Launchpad.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1695641

Comment: Disconnecting and reconnecting does not help. The only option I have is to reboot my laptop.

Comment: Try `sudo service network-manager restart`. I have the same problem, but re-connect helps.

Comment: It's getting weirder, I did  `sudo service network-manager restart` and stackoverflow is now accessible along with google websites but others are  still inacessible. In fact, I am on connected to my wifi router now and uploading this comment. And, I appreciate that you reported the bug.

Comment: I suggest that you subscribe on that bug. It looks that it is easier to reproduce it on your hardware that on mine.

Comment: And it is better to look if you have got the address, not by telling that you can open this or that site.